# Regex pattern to match a string ends with multiple charachters

Tags: python-regex

I want to match a pattern that starts with $ and ends with either dot(.) or double quote(").
I tried with this

```
re.findall(r"\$(.+?)\.",query1)
```

Above works for starting with $ and ending with .
How to add OR in ending characters so that it matches with pattern ending either with . or with "

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex pattern you want is:

```
\$(.+?)[."]
```

Your updated script:

```py
query1 = "The item cost $100.  It also is $not good\""
matches = re.findall(r"\$(.+?)[.\"]", query1)
print(matches)  # ['100', 'not good']
```

Answer (score 0):

To match both a dot or double quote, you can use a character class `[."]`

As you want to exclude matching a single character in between, you can make use of a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) to exclude matching one of them `[^".]`

```
\$([^".]+)[."]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Dai4wv/1)

Example

```
import re

query1 = 'With a dollar sign $abc. or $123"'
print(re.findall(r'\$([^".]+)[."]', query1))
```

Output

```
['abc', '123']
```

---

**Note**: as the negated character class can also match newlines, you can exclude that using:

```
 \$([^".\n]+)[."]
```